# Displaying an IQueryable result from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having an action which gives a query from a function "SearchQuery",now I want to show that query result on view.
In the below action q is Iqueryable

```
public ActionResult Index(string where)
{           
    var q = searchQuery(where);
    ViewBag.result = q;
    return View(q);
}
```

Comment: Try out learning the basics of MVC first

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the `IQueryable` to your view.

On the view, you can declare the `Model` type at the top using `@model IQueryable`. Then further down within the view you can use this by referencing `@Model`, enumerating it to show the results in a table.

A better practice would be to pass a `List` to the view (preventing the `IQueryable` from being run more than once) and using a strongly-typed model to contain the objects that you are passing through.

[See this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/19/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor.aspx) for more basic information on this.